# db2 - select portion of text

Tags: sql, db2, trim

I don't know if this is possible in DB2, but I want to select the text between two strings, for example, in the statement below, if I want to select the text between API001 and first description, how can I do this. (This text is variable)

```
<variable type="Estado">
  <estado type="String"><![CDATA[2]]></estado>
  <messages type="SystemMessage[]">
      <item>
         <message type="String"><![CDATA[API001-Call fail because this X or Y]]></message>
         <description type="String"><![CDATA[aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg]]></description>
      </item>
      <item>
         <message type="String"><![CDATA[API009-Error result of this call]]></message>
         <description type="String"><![CDATA[aaa bbb ccc ddd ssss ssss eee fff ggg]]</description>    
      </item>
      <item>
         (...)
      </item>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show your desired result, for the example data?  This looks like XML; DB2 (like most modern RDBMSs) has an XML parser, but some versions don't install it by default.  DB2 otherwise lacks a Regex parser (side note - attempting to parse XML/HTML with a Regex parser usually fails), and has somewhat lackluster standalone text-processing capabilities.

Comment: Hi, I just want "API001-Call fail because this X or Y", I tried things like trim, but this is variable, and depends the first word of the sentence.

Comment: I change the "xml" for the correct syntax

Comment: and another thing :) this column are in top of a complex query, with  a lot of subselects.